# R: Extracting part of string in a column

Tags: r

Hello stackoverflow Community,

I have the following problem in the data set. I must extract the first four symbols of the string in the column "BMI" and then transform them to numeric.

For Example: Instead of "23.3 [21.9-24.6]" -> 23.3

You can find the data here: https://github.com/tanaytuncer/LifeExpectancy_BMI

```
library(mosaic)
library(tidyverse)

path <- "/Users/tanaytuncer/Desktop/Quantitative Datenanalyse/BMI.csv"
df_BMI <- read.csv(path)
df_BMI <- df_BMI[-1:-3, ]
df_BMI <- df_BMI %>%
  rename(country = "X",
         "2000" = "X2000",
         "2001" = "X2001",
         "2002" = "X2002",
         "2003" = "X2003",
         "2004" = "X2004",
         "2005" = "X2005",
         "2006" = "X2006",
         "2007" = "X2007",
         "2008" = "X2008",
         "2009" = "X2009",
         "2010" = "X2010",
         "2011" = "X2011",
         "2012" = "X2012",
         "2013" = "X2013",
         "2014" = "X2014",
         "2015" = "X2015"
         )
df_BMI <- df_BMI %>%
  gather("year", "BMI", 2:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `substr`

```
df_BMI$BMI <- as.numeric(substr(df_BMI$BMI, 1, 4))
```

---

Or use `parse_number` from `readr`

```
library(readr)
df_BMI$BMI <- parse_number(df_BMI$BMI)
```

---

Without `gather`ing into 'long' format, we can also use `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df_BMI1 <-  df_BMI %>%
       mutate(across(-country, parse_number))
```

---

The `rename` can be avoided if we use `check.names = FALSE`

```
df_BMI <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tanaytuncer/LifeExpectancy_BMI/main/BMI.csv", check.names = FALSE)
df_BMI <- df_BMI[-1:-3, ]
names(df_BMI)[1] <- "country"
```